# circular argument reference - now rake aborted! RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I'm attempting to configure Expo: The Exchange Portal software: https://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~cszjpc/expo.html

On Ubuntu 16.04

I've been able to get far in the installingExpoonUbuntu.txt instructions, but I get thrown the following error when I call

```
RAILS_ENV='production' rake db:schema:load
```

The output:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:272: warning: circular argument reference - now rake aborted! 
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Application::Finisher
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:183:in `initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/rocco/Desktop/expo_r147/config/environment.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:218:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Finisher
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:183:in `initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/rocco/Desktop/expo_r147/config/environment.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:218:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
NameError: uninitialized constant Finisher
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:183:in `initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/rocco/Desktop/expo_r147/config/environment.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:218:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I know nothing about Rails, and are attempting to have this application up and running for a undergrad research project. Unfortunately, the research project isn't about learning Rails and its history, but perhaps I should learn it if I plan on using this software.

Any tips or suggestions?

Would any additional system information be helpful?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure but I think the problem is not with the circular argument warning, its because of those `NameError` which is because maybe you are missing some files which define those classes like `Finisher`

Comment: Try to rollback to `ruby 2.2`, or. even better, to `ruby 2.1`. The project is dated 2013.

Comment: @sajan Yeah I figured it didn't have to do with a circular argument, but i'm not quite sure if it's because I am missing any files. I might have downloaded TOO MANY versions of ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa I googled how to roll back to a previous version of ruby, and I found that I could use rvm to manage the ruby versions I want to use. I've discovered that the error is coming from my rake function.. is there a way to reconfigure the rake function so that it will point to an older version of ruby? Also, it appears that my gems aren't all in the same place. I have one version of 2.3.0 in /var/lib/gems and then a handful of different ruby version in my usr/.rvm/patches. Should I just cp the files over to the var library since rake keeps pointing in that direction?